# How to trash twoo.com incoming mail from Postfix and Procmail

Tags: regex, postfix-mta, spam, procmail

These f* people have subscribed myself in their f* service I don't want.
I first tried to unsubscribed following the link in the email.
To unsubscribe I have to login... Don't want to do that even I knew psw.

So I decided to block them in server

/etc/postfix/body_checks

```
/^(.*) twoo.com/ DISCARD
/^(.*) twoomail.com/ DISCARD
```

/etc/postfix/header_checks

```
/^(.*) twoo.com/ DISCARD
/^(.*) twoomail.com/ DISCARD
```

That didn't work so I created /home/me/.procmailrc with these directives

```
:0HB:
* ^twoo.com
/dev/null

:0HB:
* ^twoomail.com
/dev/null
```

/etc/procmailrc contains a directive to use filters from /home/user/.procmailrc (it works)

Cannot realize why I still receive mail from them in /home/me/Maildir/Inbox

Comment: Have you tried `/twoo.com/ DISCARD`? Could you also provide an example of the text, you want to match?

Comment: It is already in my post. Ah, you mean without the (.*)  No I didn't. It means something before the string, could be nothing

Comment: Yes, but you also have a space in front of `twoo.com`, which doesn't match `http://www.twoo.com`.

Comment: Ok, the blank could be the problem, I'll remove it.  So I can remove ^ too? It means the string start from the first character, I don't care.
So /string/ Discard simply matches 'string' anywhere in the line?
Same in procmailrc?  Well I don't need both!

Comment: I'm not familiar with the procmail syntax. For regular expression (that's what you're basically looking for) the `^` means _beginning of the line_, but since you want to detect `twoo.com` anywhere in our text, you don't have to add that. And it's better performance wise too. To answer your questions: yes, `/xyz/` matches _xyz_ anywhere in the line.

Comment: I made a test with procmail '*string'. No ' ^' after the asterisk and it went fine too (/var/log/procmail.log)

Comment: That's incorrect syntax; the `* ` cannot follow nothing.  (It might still do *something* but this is basically undefined behavior.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already indicated in the comments, you need to make sure your regular expression matches exactly the text you want it to match.

Postfix (optionally) uses PCRE for regular expressions, so you should be able to test at one of the many on-line regex helper sites out there; http://regex101.com/ is a popular one, but there are many more.  (Here is a demo: https://regex101.com/r/gU7gD7/1)

Procmail's regex syntax is somewhat different; if you can find a tool which offers `egrep` (aka ERE) regex syntax, that will be fairly close to what you can use with Procmail.

In particular, `/(.*) twoo.com/` requires there to be a space before `twoo.com`.  Also, the dot needs to be escaped, and once you remove the space, all of `^(.*)` is unnecessary. And of course, when a substring is optional, that's easy to specify within a single regular expression.

```
/twoo(mail)?\.com/ DISCARD
```

Similarly, the `^` anchor to require a match at beginning of line in Procmail will prevent a match anywhere else in a line.  Just remove it.

```
:0HB
* twoo(mail)?\.com
/dev/null
```

As always, you should not use locking when writing to `/dev/null` -- why would you want to prevent two processes from discarding their data at the same time?  See also http://www.iki.fi/era/procmail/mini-faq.html#locking

However, this should be unnecessary if you can get the Postfix rules to work.  Blocking at the MTA level is much superior to accepting a message and then deleting it.

Comment: I understand :0HB is enough on each filter instead of :0HB: (locking).
In my tests both filters work without escaping dots

Comment: Yes, but an unescaped dot will match any character, so you could block stuff you didn't intend to block; that's what the `twoomcom` example in the demo link would show you.

Comment: Postfix header and body checks filter all incoming mail. Procmail is useful for individual users filtering.

Comment: Absolutely; but your question is clearly about site-wide blocking.